Doubts when reading proof of implicit function theorem.
This is the theorem:

I have a lot of "small doubts" reading the proof of this theorem. I'll try to "copy-cat" it below to express my doubts. It starts with definition of a function
$$\Phi(x, y) = (f(x, y), y)$$
So, here we have "morphed" $f$ into a mapping from $(\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{p}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{p})$. Now, it is clear that
$$D\Phi(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix} D_{x}f(x, y) & D_{y}f(x, y) \\
0 & I
\end{pmatrix}$$
So that here we can conclude that
$$detD\Phi(x, y) = det(D_{x}f(x, y))$$
Then,
$$detD\Phi(x_0, y_0) = det(D_{x}f(x_0, y_0)) \neq 0$$
due to $D_{x}f(x_0, y_0)$ being invertible. This proves that $\Phi$ is regular at $(x_0, y_0)$. And thus, due to global version of inverse function, it is clear that for some open neighborhood $W_0$ of $(x_0, y_0)$ in $W$, $\Phi$ must be $C^{k}$-differomorphism. My first question:


What is the use of $f(x_0, y_0) = 0$? From this point onwards, the proof in my book does not touch on this point anymore?


The proof then proceeds to choose some neighborhood $U$ and $V_1$ of $x_0$ and $y_0$ so that $U \times V_1 \subset W_0$. Easy. Differomorphism leads to Homeomorphism and thus Open-ness. An open function maps open sets into open sets. Since $W_0$ is an open neighborhood, this is no dfficult.
Next, we can then go over to an open $W_0$ and an open $V_0$ by picking $W_0 := O$ and $V_0 := \Phi(O)$. Then, $\Phi$ is some mapping where both its domain $W_0$ and rang $V_0$ are open; more importantly, $\Phi$ is now $C^{k}$ differomorphism so that we can now build an inverse $\Psi \in C^{k}(V_0, W_0)$ of $\Phi$.
What happens next is a simple manipulation of the definition of $\Psi$ and then making use of the "open-ness of $V_0$"



It is easy to see why such $V$ is open? But why does $V$ open-ness
matter here? We still have the fact that $\psi$ is $C^{k}$-mapping without it,
right?


The whole proof:  Proof

We need the function to vanish at some point of the domain for the last argument to hold.

Can you make it clear? Where does the vanish come to the picture? Why the open-ness of $V$?

@Jason Aha. Take $z = 0$. Didn't see it. Quite a bunch of details in the proof. Thank you. Why the open-ness, tho?

@Jason I see. Open implies open neighborhood. It is required in the theorem statement.

The whole point of the theorem is to show the existence of a function $\psi$ such that $f(x, \psi(x)) = 0$. But more specifically, for any non-singular solution $(x_0,y_0)$ of $f(x,y) = 0$, to show that there is such a $\psi$ with $\psi(x_0) = y_0$. The condition $f(x_0,y_0) = 0$ in the theorem is just establishing $(x_0, y_0)$ as the solution for which it is defining $\psi$. If $f(x_0, y_0) \ne 0$, then either $\psi(x_0) \ne y_0$ or $f(x_0, \psi(x_0)) \ne 0$, contrary to the theorems claims.
